# Angular with .NET core WEBAPI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to interact between 2 angular application by passing values?

I have 2 angular applications: application 1 (angular) invokes application 2 (angular) using an iFrame.
When invoking the application2, application 1 pass some values using param and I want to get the values from application 1 and load the values on to application 2. How can I implement it?

What I thought is can I create 2 endpoints one to get the request (Postrequest from app1) from application 2 and another endpoint to pass the values to application2 (get request in app2) using .net C#.  Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

You would probably need:

- a server that your Angular applications connect to
- your Angular application acting as a publisher (sends data using websockets/API endpoint)
- your Angular application acting as a subscriber (receives data using websocket).

Your server would act as a pub-sub broker and allow:

- applications can subscribe by connecting to a websocket
- applications can publish by calling endpoint / connecting to websocket and sending messages to it.

You will probably have to maintain a list of clients on your server to broadcast messages to.

Websockets are supported in both TypeScript and .NET.

Comment: MS also uses signalR as their websocket. But for the OP, I'd skip the iframe bit

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need the data in the backend, just between the front end applications you can use `postMessage` to send data between the applications. That way everything is kept within the browser and you can send whatever information you want between the frames/applications.